# how to specify host using ip address instead of name to connect to postgres database using netbeans in a java project?

Tags: java, postgresql, networking, netbeans, localhost

i want to add database to my netbeans java project using ip address.
my question is that when i specify hostname by name that is "localhost" followed my correct details in the new connection wizard in netbeans connection establishes succesfully. this is as shown below.[image: host by name]

but when i specify host by specifying ip address of my own computer that is localhost connection doesn't get established. same is shown below[image: ipconfig]
[image: host my ip]

well my motive is not to put ip of localhost but of another pc for remote database sharing over internet. but i think the problem lies in the method of specifying host using ip. if i get it right database sharing might work between different hosts as well. 
also any other methods of sharing postgres database over the internet are also welcome.

 i am a newbie in java as well as netbeans so any help is appreciated.

Comment: There's no way I can read any of those screen grabs.  Can you edit them so just the relevant text is visible.  Although looking and the sub-pixel text, it doesn't appear to be "127.0.0.1" so try that for your IP address.

Comment: @user2338547 well i have updated the screen and the ip address is same as that shows in ipconfig command as shown

Comment: What is the value of `listen_address` in `postgresql.conf`?

Comment: And does your firewall allow connections to your IP address?  Can you ping that IP address?  This is more of a network configuration problem than anything, although verifying your postgres config too as mentioned above is also necessary.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name value of listen_address in **postgresql.conf** is * which i changed to my system's ip address. will that help.

Comment: @user2338547 yes i can my system's ip address!! and i have really no idea on how to check whether firewall allows connections to my ip address!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sense of thinking that `localhost` is your IP-Address is itself wrong!You need to have a loop-back address which will direct your operations to itself and not as the case of your IP-Address shown in ipconfig command.

You need to specify this `127.0.0.1` as the IP-Address.
127.0.0.1 is the most-commonly used IPv4 loopback address.

Try this :- `jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/nic_project_db`

> **localhost** means this computer. It is a hostname that the computer's
>   software and users may employ to access the computer's own network
>   services via its loopback network interface. Using the loopback
>   interface bypasses local network interface hardware.    // Taken from Wikipedia.

Comment: thanks for help it worked but my motive is to connect database to another host over internet how would i do that if keep on using a standard loopback addrress?

Comment: Well,if you want to connect on a remote machine having a different IP,you simply provide his IP-Address and the port number which can connect you with his database(PostgreSQL here).Probably,the default is what you mentioned---5432,but change it to the default!

Comment: tried that a zillion times but always get some error like
"Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections."

Answer (score 1):

For future reference to anyone that might have same question here is solution:

In the postgresql database folder open up the postgresql.conf file. Add the following line:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Then open up the pg_hba.conf file and add the following line:

```
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```